# python raw string notation throwing error with trailing slash

Tags: python

I'm trying to set a path to a string variable in python using raw string notation and am getting an error with the trailing slash:

```
datapath = r'C:\path\to\my\data\'
```

gives me an "EOL while scanning string literal" error

I thought raw string notation was supposed to make everything in the string literal. Can someone explain this to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an exception for the end quote of the string because:

```
C:\path\to\my\data\'
```

sees `'` literally since the previous backslash isn't seen as an escape char, so string parsing continues.

So as frustrating as it is, you have to do `r'C:\path\to\my\data\\'`

Answer (score 1):

The documentation defines a string literal in this way:

```
stringliteral   ::=  [stringprefix](shortstring | longstring)
```

You're using the **r** stringprefix.

Then we have these definitions for characters in the strings:

```
shortstringchar ::=  <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>
longstringchar  ::=  <any source character except "\">
```

where you will notice that the backwards slash is *not* one of the characters allowed in a *shortstring* or a *longstring*.