# How to concatenate a backlash to string in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a string "foo" that I need to concatenate a "\" to the front of the string.

If I do it like this:

```
s = "foo"
s = "\" + s
# Gets EOL while scanning string literal error
```

Now if I do it like this:

```
    s = "\\" + s
```

print(s) then outputs:

```
"\foo"
```

But...

```
s = s.encode('utf-8')
print(s)
```

Outputs:

```
b'\\foo'
```

I need a single slash when it gets utf-8 encoded.

Comment: you're still seeing the representation of the `bytes` object but it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when printing a `bytes` object (as returned by `encode`), `print` prints you the *representation* of the object, where the backslash is doubled.

But if you decode the object again you get only one slash:

```
s = r"\foo".encode('utf-8')
print(s.decode('utf-8'))
```

result:

```
\foo
```

also note that (on the `bytes` object):

```
>>> print(chr(s[0]))
\
>>> print(chr(s[1]))
f
```

*there's only one slash in the bytes object*

(aside: you cannot use `"\"` or even `r"\"` since the string parsing wouldn't be able to see the end of the string, see one of my older answers [python raw string notation throwing error with trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491342/python-raw-string-notation-throwing-error-with-trailing-slash))

Comment: The reason I have to add the \ is because some of the elements of the string have to be calculated. I have other elements in the string that are static, that include a \ in the same format. When I print that encoded string, the ones that were concatenated show \\ and the ones that were defined without concatenating show \. So there is a difference

Comment: that's probably a raw string issue. `\\foo` isn't like `\foo` because `\f` is interpreted. Either use double slash or use raw prefix.

Comment: This is correct, but not with ascii formatting which is what I really needed. Thanks for your help.